# Hide Submit button on Page Load

Tags: php, jquery

In a php page I have placed a submit button,

**HTML:**

```
<input type="submit" name="btnAdd" id="btnAdd" Value="Add">
```

I need to hide this button (using jQuery) when link is cliked,

**Link:**

```
echo  '<a href=" '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" onClick="MyFunction()"> Edit </a>';
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function MyFunction(){      
             $('btnAdd').hide();
         });
</script>
```

But this code does not hide the button as expected. How can I fix this?

Comment: an ID is called with a # sign, `'#btnAdd'`

Comment: ... in CSS selectors (including your jQuery selector), not in the HTML, just to clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a wrong selector. You need to use `#btnAdd` for an [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyFunction() {      
        $('#btnAdd').hide();
    }
</script>
```

Also you should put the `MyFunction` function **outside** of the `document.ready` callback to avoid making it privately scoped.

Another possibility is to do this unobtrusively:

```
echo  '<a href=" '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" id="edit"> Edit </a>';
```

which seems easier to be written as:

```
<a href="#" id="edit">Edit</a>
```

and then subscribe for the [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event of the edit link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#edit').click(function() {
            $('#btnAdd').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm interesting to know. Do you prefer the unobtrusive version?

Comment: Don't you thing the unobtrusive adapt the "Write more, do the same" technique?

Comment: @gdoron, no, I don't think so.